# Java key input is different to KeyEvent's VK keys

Tags: java, awt, keylistener, keyevent

I'm trying to compare the key code I get from `KeyEvent.getKeyCode()` from a key listener to something like `KeyEvent.VK_SLASH` however when I press the slash key (and I know it's slash because it shows a /), the comparison (`if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SLASH)`) is false.

However when I compare it to `KeyEvent.VK_DEAD_ACUTE`, it returns true.

Other keys such as ABCD or numbers are fine however some keys such as ` and / are different.

Why is this? And how can I fix this?

Edit: Other keys such as ' are affected too as it produces a `. And pressing the` key gives me `VK_DEFINED`

Comment: `VK_SLASH` could be a backslash too, right? Like this -> \\.

Comment: Also what type of keyboard are you using?

Comment: What OS? What version of Java.  Works okay on MacOS

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. The keyboard I'm using is a really old SIEMENS keyboard from like the 90's... But pressing the slash key does give me a '/' so I doubt it's the keyboards fault. The backslash key has it's own key code `KeyEvent.VK_BACKSLASH` .

Comment: I think Anubian Noob meant what keyboard *layout* are you using?

Comment: Then in that case, it's a UK keyboard layout? It's QWERTY.

Comment: I'm stumped because it works fine for me. Perhaps you have some foreign layout or IME enabled in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using

`Key = e.getKeyCode();`

then do

```
if( Key == KeyEvent.VK_SLASH){
    ...
}
```